Как подбирать предметы по кнопке?
у меня есть скрипт с методом, где при приближению к предмету, появляется кнопка. При нажатии кнопки предмет удаляется. Проблема в том, что удаляются все предметы c этим скриптом, а нужен чтоб только этот предмет пропал. Буду очень благодарен
void Update()
{
    TakeItem();
}
 
void TakeItem()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
 
    if (Physics.Raycast(beginRay.transform.position, beginRay.transform.forward, out hit, distance ) 
&& hit.collider.tag == "Bullet" && isTake == false)
    {
        F_button.SetActive(true);
 
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F) && isTake != true)
        {
            isTake = true;
            F_button.SetActive(false);
            Debug.Log("пули");
            //Destroy(gameObject, 1f);
        }
    }
    else
        F_button.SetActive(false);
}


Вы удаляйте все объекты на которых висит этот скрипт, а вам нужно удалять объект с которым происходит рэйкаст столкновение, для этого используйте:
Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject, 1f);


еще проблема в том, что при нажатии ящики сразу все активируются, т.е. забираются сразу все

не знаю как это реализовано у вас, попробуйте точно так-же присваивать значение isTake только объекту который закастили

а как это сделать? что-то я туплю, уже часов 6 над этим и безрезультатно

@никитосик заместо Raycast используйте RaycastAll и выбирайте из массива ближайший к Вам объект дока
